# What causes an Angular app to load it's components halfway through the page?

Tags: angular, scroll, angular6, loading

**Context:**

I've been developing a portfolio page and wanted to put my knowledge of Angular to use. All was going fine on localhost but when I deployed, saw that the page would load mid-page.

[A better example of what I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vHL0.png)

Through GitHub, I saw that this was a [reported problem](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7791) and have tried a few suggested workarounds that haven't changed anything so I come humbly to you, oh mighty Stack Overflow, to see if anyone had either suggestions of workarounds or an explanation as to why that happens in the first place.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not get a clear picture from the image you shared. The github link you shared is an issue of incorrect scroll position in the upcoming route. Is that your problem ?

Comment: I have faced this in past.  I am not sure of the root cause but you can always fix this with scrolling to top programtically using `window.scroll(0,0)`. Do this in your `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use window's scroll method in `ngOnInit()`.

```
window.scroll(0,0);
```

ngAfterVIewChecked is called every time Angular has finished running change detection on a component and it's children.

So you can also try to set in `ngAfterVIewChecked()` method.

Comment: @sara you can up vote the answer so it'll also helps to other developers also. And I'm happy to help you.

Comment: hey! I did but as I don’t have my 15 first points yet my upvotes don’t count sadly

Comment: It's fine @SaraVasquez. You can do that when you have enough reputation.